# Why is my Haskell code saying 'variable not in scope: main'?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

When I type the following in the interactive shell of Haskell on the [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/haskell) website, it works perfectly.

```
let squareMe x = x * x
let myFruit = ["banana", "apple", "kiwi", "orange"]
```

But when I type it into a source file and click 'Run' I get the error:

```
<interactive>:3:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: main
    • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
```

I've been trying to understand this error and come up with a solution for a couple of hours now and am no nearer to finding a solution or understanding what the error means.

Comment: A program requires an entry point: a monadic function called `main`.

Comment: What you wrote is not really correct. The code isn't complete (I miss `main`). Also, please check [*let it be*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#let-it-be). I suggest to read that book from start.

Answer (score 27):

The Haskell REPL (GHCi) and actual Haskell programs are considerably different.

The reasons for this difference is the goal of the two formats. Firstly, GHCi is a testing area, not a code-running area. However, Haskell source files are meant to run a certain process, which is named `main`. When you run a source file, the Haskell compiler (usually GHC) looks for the `IO` action called `main`, and tries to run it. In this case, there was no `main`, so it failed.

Secondly, what you typed is not a valid Haskell program, those are declarations that would be fine in GHCi, but not in Haskell source. This would be correct in a source file:

```
squareMe x = x * x

myFruit = ["banana", "apple", "kiwi", "orange"]
```

Note the lack of `let`; Haskell source files don't use it to declare things.

Note that on repl.it, this will still complain that `main` is missing, but you can then refer to `squareMe` and `myFruit` in the REPL without worry. In other words, the error will still appear, but it doesn't matter, because you can use whatever you wrote in the file nonetheless.

If you wanted to suppress the warning, you could write the lines:

```
main :: IO ()    -- This says that main is an IO action.
main = return () -- This tells main to do nothing.
```

There are many things you could have the program do instead of this. Here are a couple of examples:

- `main = putStrLn "No errors!"` Will print `No errors!` when you run it.
- `main = print myFruit` Will print `["banana", "apple", "kiwi", "orange"]` when you run it.

Please note that this answer applies mostly to the site repl.it specifically, though in general this is how Haskell programs are structured.

Answer (score 9):

If you compile a Haskell source there needs to be a `main` symbol as entry point, just like when compiling e.g. a C program. Also in a compiled file you must skip the `let`s. E.g.

```
squareMe x = x * x

main = putStrLn . show $ squareMe 4
```

Comment: There's no need to use `show` within `print`: that is already polymorphic on the input type.

Comment: `print x = putStrLn (show x)`, so your code calls `show` twice.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, indeed. `print` probably shouldn't even be in the prelude, since it becomes the wrong function as soon as you want to piece together output from multiple values, or add newlines, or whatever. `print = putStrLn . show`, `readLn = readIO =<< getLine`, and neither of these convenience functions seems worth the didactic overhead.

Comment: @dfeuer I find `print` too handy to agree with that. In fact I'd be more inclined to say `Show` and `Read` shouldn't be in the prelude. (One should very seldom feel the need to convert anything to/from string, _except_ for the purpose of doing IO with those strings.)

Comment: Thanks, edited the answer and replaced the `print` with `putStrLn`.

Answer (score 1):

If what you’re writing is more like a library or a set of utility routines than a complete program, you can declare it as a `module`.  Then GHC will compile it to an object you can link to other programs, and you can also load it in GHCI.  It will not be expected to contain a `main` routine.

If you save this to a `.hs` file:

```
module Example (squareMe) where

squareMe x = x * x -- Exported to other modules.
myFruit = ["banana", "apple", "kiwi", "orange"] -- Not exported.
```

Compiling this with GHC will give you a `.hi` file and a `.o` file, and running it in GHCI will give you this:

```
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Ok, modules loaded: Example (sx-modulexmpl.o).
Prelude Example> squareMe 2
4
```

You can also compute an expression that references a library from the command line.  `ghc -e "squareMe 2" Example.hs` prints `4`.