# How to solve basic error compile in haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

Hello everyone I just start leraning Haskell and every code I'm going to compile its giving me the same error:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: main
    • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
```

Just expect to learn how to compile in haskell

Comment: You define a `main`

Comment: What commands are you running? Presumably you're compiling some file like `ghc MyFile.hs` is that right? If so, what are the conents of that file?

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46547208/7203016) help?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr thank you it work.   When i compile it don't show error. But I think my code its no right . I compile it i don't do nothing main :: IO ()
main = return ()

soma :: [Int] -> Int
soma [] = 0
soma (h:t) = h + soma t

Comment: It would help if you explained how you are using Haskell.  Are you running it from an online IDE like `repl.it`, are you using a local IDE like Visual Studio Code, or are you running `ghc` and `ghci` from the command line?  Also, are you running on Linux or Windows?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Using ghc from command line  on linux

Comment: If you want to add code to clarify, please edit your question. Comments are not theplace for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a Haskell source file named `Exemplo.hs`.  The name should be spelled exactly like that, starting with an uppercase "E".  The first line of the file should be a `module` statement that uses the same module name as the name of the source file:

```
module Exemplo where  -- "Exemplo" here should match filename "Exemplo.hs"

soma :: [Int] -> Int
soma [] = 0
soma (h:t) = h + soma t
```

Now, in the interactive GHC prompt (that you get by running `ghci`), you can load this file (with `:load Exemplo`) and test your function.  Using the command line, it will look like this:

```
~/src/overflow$ ghci
GHCi, version 9.4.7: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> :load Exemplo
[1 of 1] Compiling Exemplo          ( Exemplo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
ghci> soma [1,2,3,4,5]
15
ghci>
```

If you want to create a compiled executable, you must create a source file that defines a `main` function, and this function will determine what the program does.  You can name the source file whatever you like, but you should **NOT** include a `module` statement.  For example, create a file `Programa.hs` containing the lines:

```
soma :: [Int] -> Int
soma [] = 0
soma (h:t) = h + soma t

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a list of numbers in Haskell syntax (e.g., [1,2,3,4,5]):"
  numbers <- readLn
  putStrLn "The sum is:"
  print (some numbers)
```

Now, you can compile this program with `ghc` and run the resulting executable.  It will look like this:

```
~/src/overflow$ ghc Programa
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Programa.hs, Programa.o )
[2 of 2] Linking Programa
~/src/overflow$ ./Programa
Enter a list of numbers in Haskell syntax (e.g., [1,2,3,4,5]):
[1,2,3,4,5]   <--- I entered this part
The sum is:
15
~/src/overflow$
```

For a slightly more complete answer:  GHC uses a module system where each file is a single module.  A file can either start with a `module XXX where` statement that names the module, or you can leave out the `module` statement, in which case the `Main` module is assumed.  When one module imports another module using an import statement:

```
import SomeModule
```

the compiler will try to find the module in the file `SomeModule.hs`, so it is important that the module name in the `module SomeModule where` statement matches the module name in the filename.  Module names must start with an uppercase letter, so this means that Haskell source files that are supposed to be modules should also be named starting with an uppercase letter.  Creating a module in `Exemplo.hs` will work, but `exemplo.hs` might not.

The `Main` module is special.  When you compile a file (or load a file with GHCi) that contains a `module Main where` statement in the first line or doesn't contain a `module` statement at all (and so defaults to being the `Main` module), the compiler expects it to be a standalone program instead of a regular module, and it looks for a `main` function.  With older versions of GHC, you'll get a cryptic error message that maybe you meant `min`.  Newer versions of GHC give a slightly better error message:

```
Main.hs:1:1: error:
    The IO action ‘main’ is not defined in module ‘Main’
```

So, this means:

1. If you want to create a Haskell source file that is *not* a standalone program but instead contains functions that you want to test interactively with GHCi or compile into a module that can be `import`ed by other modules, then you should name it something other than `Main.hs`, you should make sure the first letter of the filename is uppercase, and you should include a module `module MyModule where` statement at the top that matches the filename `MyModule.hs`.
2. If you want to create a Haskell source file that is a standalone program, you can name it anything you want, with or without an uppercase letter.  You should leave out the `module` statement, and you must define a `main` function that defines what the standalone program will actually do when it's run.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to compile it both ways.